# How to factor $2x^3-5x-3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

How can we factor $2x^3-5x-3$?

I couldn't do any work in this expression, please help.

Comment: Guess for an integer root $r$ (not difficult in this case). After finding it, divide your expression by $x-r$

Comment: $\;x=-1\;$ is a root.

Comment: I think $x+1$ is a factor. Use long division to find the other.

Comment: The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) means that if there are rational roots, then they must be among $1, \frac12, \frac 32$ or $3$, or the negative of any of those. Before trying anything too fancy, you should try those eight.

Comment: Use [this classical method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) noting that $-1$ is a root of your polynomial.

Comment: You can use either the fact that:
$$ 2x^3- 5x - 3 = 2x^3-2x - 3x -3 = 2x(x^2-1)- 3(x+1) = \ldots$$

Comment: Rational root theorem, synthetic division, quadratic formula.

Comment: we can depend on the following
$$2(x+1)^3=2x^3+6x^2+6x+2$$
so
$$2x^3-5x-3=2x^3+6x^2+6x+2-6x^2-6x-2-5x-3$$
$$2(x+1)^3-(6x^2+11x+5)=0$$
$$2(x+1)^3-(x+1)(6x+5)=0$$
$$(x+1)(2(x+1)^2-(6x+5))=0$$
$$(x+1)(2x^2-2x-3)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

the best way to factor polynomials greater than degree two is through the use of 
[Polynomial Long Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division/%22Polynomial%20long%20division%22).  Via inspection it appears that one root is $x = -1$, and a quick check verifies this: $2(-1)^{3} - 5(-1) - 3 = -2 + 5 - 3 = 0$.  It should be pretty easy to proceed from there

Answer (score 1):

You can add subtract terms to get common $x+1$.
$$2x^3-5x-3=2x^3+2x^2-2x^2-5x-3$$
I added and subtracted $2x^2$to get $x+1$ common.
$$2x^2(x+1)-2x^2-2x+2x-5x-3=2x^2(x+1)-2x(x+1)-3x-3$$
Now,I added and subtracted $2x$.
$$2x^2(x+1)-2x(x+1)-3(x+1)=(x+1)(2x^2-2x-3)$$
At last, I got $x+1$ common.

Answer (score -1):

Look this factorization

$$ 2x^3-5x-3=(x+1) (2 x^2-2 x-3)$$

or

$$2x^3-5x-3=-\frac12 (-2 x+\sqrt{7}+1) (x+1) (2 x+\sqrt{7}-1)$$

Comment: And how on earth would the asker come up with this?

Comment: The question is a really basic one: if you want to answer you'll have to explain how to reason, instead of just giving out the solution.